# 10.1.31-MariaDB keeps restarting no errors nor warnings

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This was happening before, but it started happening more frequently since I switched all of my databases to InnoDB storage engine.

This is a log

```
2018-02-07  1:50:25 139991235894016 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
2018-02-07  1:50:25 139991235894016 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2018-02-07  1:50:25 139989190948608 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2018-02-07  1:50:25 139991235894016 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2018-02-07  1:50:26 139991235894016 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for page_cleaner to finish flushing of buffer pool
2018-02-07  1:50:27 139991235894016 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2399453669
2018-02-07  1:50:28 139991235894016 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-02-07  1:50:29 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-02-07  1:50:30 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-02-07  1:50:30 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-02-07  1:50:30 140442372299008 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-83.0 started; log sequence number 2399453669
2018-02-07  1:50:30 140440259000064 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2018-02-07  1:50:30 140442372299008 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-02-07  1:50:30 140442372299008 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-02-07  1:50:30 140442372299008 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.31-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2018-02-07 12:25:12 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-02-07 12:25:13 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2442989712
2018-02-07 12:25:29 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 1628 .ibd/.isl files
2018-02-07 12:25:45 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Processed 3190 .ibd/.isl files
2018-02-07 12:25:52 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2018-02-07 12:25:52 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Read redo log up to LSN=2442991616
2018-02-07 12:25:52 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 7 pages from redo log
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140540657391872 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-83.0 started; log sequence number 2442991369
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140538537805568 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140540657391872 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140540657391872 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140540657391872 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2018-02-07 12:25:54 140540657391872 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2018-02-07 12:25:55 140540657391872 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-02-07 12:25:56 140540657391872 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.31-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-02-07 13:08:35 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2449456998
2018-02-07 13:08:36 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2018-02-07 13:08:37 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 14 pages from redo log
2018-02-07 13:08:38 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-02-07 13:08:38 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-02-07 13:08:38 140240817621248 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-83.0 started; log sequence number 2449478669
2018-02-07 13:08:39 140240817621248 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-02-07 13:08:39 140240817621248 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2018-02-07 13:08:39 140240817621248 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2018-02-07 13:08:39 140240817621248 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2018-02-07 13:08:39 140238703789824 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2018-02-07 13:08:39 140240817621248 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2018-02-07 13:08:39 140240817621248 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.31-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

This is my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/censored.censored.com.err
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=500M
tmp_table_size=320M
max_heap_table_size=320M
max_connections=200
innodb_log_file_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
join_buffer_size = 1M
table_open_cache = 16000
table_definition_cache = 16000
thread_cache_size=4
open_files_limit = 24000
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 512K
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 128M
key_buffer_size=128M
performance_schema = ON
wait_timeout=90
max_user_connections=30
```

As I see no errors or the real reason this could happen

it looks like i'm running out of mememory I recently upgraded I have 8GB of ram..

[image: RAM Usage]

[image: MySQL Data]

[image: MySQL Queries]

[image: MySQL Connections]

These high peaks from 1-3AM are because of backup.

As you can see mysql seems gracefully restarting, but why?

*EDIT:*

**/var/log/messages**

```
Feb  7 13:08:28 aurora systemd: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb  7 13:08:28 aurora systemd: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Feb  7 13:08:28 aurora systemd: mariadb.service failed.
Feb  7 13:08:33 aurora systemd: mariadb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.


Feb  7 12:25:06 aurora systemd: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb  7 12:25:06 aurora systemd: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Feb  7 12:25:06 aurora systemd: mariadb.service failed.
Feb  7 12:25:11 aurora systemd: mariadb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
```

Comment: I suspect opcache eating all of my memory i set limits too high. I'm gonna reduce that. and come back

Comment: Please post complete results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%;  B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%;  C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%';   D) mysqltuner.com report, if available, even if less than 1 day of uptime.

Comment: Use of mysqlcalculator.com will help you understand where your RAM is being used.  The defaults in the 'per connection' group work quite well.  2 minutes at this web site will be very helpful.

Comment: The MySQL is fine. The historically max connection usage is not more than 100. Max memory possible reach is 2.5gb. the issue wasn't MySQL the issue was opcache values set too high

Comment: So, have you determined why mariadb.service was killed with status=9?
This is a central part of keeping MySQL running.
Please post complete results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%; B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%; C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%'; D) complete mysqltuner.com report, if available, even if less than 1 day of uptime.

Comment: I have determined the cause of MySQL being killed by kernel almost immediately after posting this question. AS I said the reason was PHPs Opcache which was set to 1024, i reduced it to 192. 
THank you for your mysql tuning tips, my queries are pretty fast my mysql was already tuned. I listened to you about raising instances from 1 to 8, implementing pool dump and pool load and raising thread cache size to 100.

https://pastebin.com/HHRDKqBm

Comment: Is that "queries per second"?  Are you using MyISAM entirely?  You should seriously consider switching to InnoDB.  Do you really have 16000 tables?  Even if you do, do you need the cache to be that big?  Is any Swap space allocated on the server?  What metric is used for "Threads"?  (Perhaps "Threads_running"?)  Lower `max_connections` to 100.

Comment: I switched to InnoDB entirely 10 min after writing this post. I converted all the tables and set default storage engine to InnoDB. Yes, I need a cache that big I have 4000 open tables with the tendency of growing. I do not have swap. I will lower amount of connections to 100.

Comment: @Luka - Recommend having some swap space, but setting "swappiness" (if your OS has such) to 1 (percent).  This should prevent odd spikes in memory from killing MySQL.  (Although I see not clue of such.)

Comment: @Luka - please provide `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` (preferably after a day of uptime); there may be more clues lurking there.

Answer (score 1):

Things to do in [mysqld] section of
my.cnf

```
#max_allowed_packet=500M  # disable default is 1M  when needed in SESSION,
```

SET @max_allowed_packet=1000000000  # for a 1G size, abbreviation not allowed
1G is the max tolerated according to refman

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8 # from 1 to minimize mutex contention
innodb_page_cleaners=64  # will autolimit to be = b p instances
#join_buffer_size = 1M  # disable to allow default to work for you
thread_cache_size=100  # V8 CAP to avoid OOM
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from 2K to for higher QC capacity
innodb_print_all_deadlocks=ON  # you need it in your error log and correct
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=ON # to prepare for WARM start
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON  # to avoid warmup time
expire_logs_days=5  # to cover the weekends
```

Comment: Many people recommend that 1 buffer pool instance is recommended per 1gb. My buffer pool size is 1g so if it was 8gb I would set 8 instances. Are you sure 8 instances would be beneficial for 1gb buffer pool size? Also QC is not used much with this values so I intentionally set 2k so i Can cache all minor queries.

Comment: Would 8 instances improve write efficiency for innodb buffer pool of 1gb? Also I am confused regarding thread cache size many experts recommend to set it to number of cores on the machine. Are you sure 100 is way to go?

Comment: Another interesting quote "The innodb_page_cleaners default value was changed from 1 to 4 in MySQL 5.7.8. *If the number of page cleaner threads exceeds the number of buffer pool instances, innodb_page_cleaners is automatically set to the same value as innodb_buffer_pool_instances* "

Comment: You will not hurt anything with innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8; - this will help avoid mutex contention and position you for ideal count of 8 when you have enough data and RAM to support 8G of innodb_buffer_pool_size.  Each buffer_pool_instance will be 1/8 of the size of the bp.  This is readily visible when you look at results of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;  Look at SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'threads_created';  If result is over 100, make thread_cache_size=100;  and NO more.  To avoid OOM.

Comment: Page_cleaners  set it to 64 and when you acquire more RAM, you will not have to REMEMBER to adjust innodb_page_cleaners to match innodb_buffer_pool_instances.
If you could post MySQLTuner.com complete report, it would be very helpful, after you have been on line for at least one working day, 7 days would be better.

Comment: I have no more innodb data than ~600mb so innodb buffer pool size of 1gb is enough for me. I  have no more than 20-30% ram available because of opcache caching so I can not increase the pool to 8gb nor I see the reason to do so. But I will increase instances like you said. I'm already using mysqltuner and tuning primer but I do not blindly follow the instructions I always do a research what each variable does. My queries pretty fast are being executed my main problem is php code execution time that is why I talk about opcache so much.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8zxeSu0.gif as you can see i barely got it stable

Comment: Keep in mind, innodb_change_buffer_max_size default of 25% is set aside first thing from innodb_buffer_pool_size.  Effectively when you get near 750M of data, go to 2G to ensure innodb is running as smooth as possible for many months.  Barely stable is much better than restarting out of the wild blue yonder.

Comment: @Luka - `thread_cache_size` has impact on frequency of _creating new_ processes (threads); that should be totally unrelated to cores.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - `max_connections` can threaten to chew up logs of RAM (and lead to OOM); `thread_cache_size` cannot.

Comment: @Luka - `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should never be set as high as the server's RAM.  That _will_ lead to OOM.  70% is a better recommendation.  Even less if you are mostly MyISAM.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - Although your recommendation of 2G is reasonable for an 8GB server, the rationale of keeping it bigger than the data may be unnecessary -- remember that the buffer_pool is a _cache_.  If it is not big enough, things _may_ slow down; not "be unstable".

Comment: @rickjames  Just trying to cover 'many months' without a 'slow down'.  It is quite likely rows are added every working day, new talent may join the party and push even more data toward the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have 6 PHP versions
**54, 55, 56, 70, 71, 72**

and for 5 of them, I enabled opcache and set memory to **1024** which I realized is extreme. Why would I cache too many files in such amount which probably won't be even needed in the future accesses which obviously leads to memory overload?
So I reduced it to 192 and 16 for strings.

After that I see stability. Finally...

[image]

So MySQL wasn't the cause.

Comment: If results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'threads_created' needs 8 added for overhead minimum to support all the thing MySQL does behind the scenes.  For more robust response time, add SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_used_connections' to this number and you will ensure 'threads_created' is not going wild.  The number of thread_cache_size should never be > 100 in your my.cnf/ini.  This capacity limit will help prevent OOM caused crashes.

Comment: If that means an extra 1GB for caching in PHP, that probably won't explain anything.  (I have never used such; it does not see worth the effort.)